# How to get the list of objects with smallest date from a list of objects with a dates?

Tags: c#

I created a simple class that represents a project:

```
class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have a list of these. I want a list of objects (players) with the newest dates (the youngest players) , than there are multiple players with exactly the same birth date. How do I do that?

Comment: Group by `BirthDate`, sort, grab the first element (group)?

Comment: @David Group by or Order by?

Comment: @Duston: First one, then the other.  (Which one is first may not even matter.)

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem by using a little primitive method.

I generate random objects

```
public List<Player> Players = new List<Player>
        {
            new Player(){ Name="elcin", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-234)},
            new Player(){ Name="kazim", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4)},
            new Player(){ Name="emin", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-34)},
            new Player(){ Name="sasa", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-234)},
            new Player(){ Name="dada", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-44444)},  
            new Player(){ Name="fafa", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-42)},
            new Player(){ Name="gaga", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-24)},
            new Player(){ Name="xaxa", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2234)},   
            new Player(){ Name="caca", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-124)},
        };
```

Then I created an object named sorted for the listed players.

```
List<Player> sorted = new List<Player>();
```

I sorted the list using recursive method.

```
public void SortedList(List<Player> players)
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            DateTime minDate = DateTime.Now;
            foreach(var item in players)
            {
                if(minDate>item.BirthDate)
                {
                    minDate = item.BirthDate;
                    player = item;
                }
            }
            players.Remove(player);
            sorted.Add(player);
            if (players.Count!=0)
            {
                SortedList(players);
            }
        }
```

To preview it briefly, I send a List object to the `SortedList` method and get my object listed in the `sorted` object outside of the Method.

Appreciate if you found it. **USEFUL**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way solving this issue is by grouping the collection by the birthday, than taking the group with the latest date and flatten that group.

```
  listOfPlayers.GroupBy(e => e.BirthDate)
               .OrderByDescending(e => e.Key)
               .Take(1)
               .SelectMany(e => e)
               .ToList();
```